# How to show last 20 comments using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comment table where all the comment are stored and i want to show the last 20 comments

```
$query="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE answerid=$answerid ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20";
```

It gives me last 20 but from top to down,But i want to get them in down to top .Means last comment(by time) should be shown at last
i used

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$newresult = array_reverse($result);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($newresult) ) {
    //my code 
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

but this doesn't work?

Comment: change `DESC` to `ASC LIMIT 0,20`

Comment: @diEcho how will that give the last 20?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka then what it will return?

Comment: @diEcho it will give only first 20 comment

Comment: @diEcho it'll return the first 20 comments. he wants the last 20 comments in ascending order.. Ross smith gave the correct answer. Please check it

Comment: and  what about `ASC` i said change to `DESC` with `ASC LIMIT 0,20` means there will be `time` before these text

Comment: i really dont know what is the usage of using subquery when it can be done by simple way.

Comment: @diEcho your query will give only first 20 comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM comment WHERE answerid=$answerid ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20
) d ORDER BY time
```

Comment: it says'Every derived table must have its own alias'..what does this mean...?

Comment: Sorry, add a 'd' after the ')' and that error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

`$query="SELECT * FROM comment WHERE answerid=$answerid ORDER BY time ASC";`

Comment: if there are 200 comment than it will give me only first 20 comment..

Comment: Before the OP edited their question, there was no `LIMIT 20` clause and this was the correct answer. Now this answer has been invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

This works fine if the column id is auto_increment. 
You can also change DESC to ASC in your code!

Comment: doesn't matter my query gives me right result but in reverse order